# UILocalNotification doesn't play sound when app is in foreground

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am using `UILocalNotification` in my app. It does not play any sound when my app is in the foreground, but when my app goes in to the background it works fine (it plays the sound.) Why?

Answer (score 4):

That's how notifications work.  From the documentation:

> If the application is running in the foreground, there is no alert,
>   badging, or sound; instead, the
>   `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method is called if the
>   delegate implements it.

If you want to respond to a notification while your app is running, you need to do that yourself in your app delegate:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:    (UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    // Play your sound, display a message, etc.
}
```